# Simple rewrite rule isn't working on third level domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a third level domain *m.numeroverde.com* with these htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

404 error page is shown correctly on actual 404 pages, but *m.numeroverde.com/home* also is recognized as 404 page, when it should be linked to the index.php page.

Do I have to write something in my htaccess for a third level domain?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: I did what you suggest @anubhava, like this:

`fgdxhcjjiuygfdv bdgfx hsbgx fhgx
asd

RewdriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`

... It does not generates a 500 error, but it shows my custom 404 page! I tried to replace `404.html` with `400.html`, just for testing, and it generates the defauly 404 Apache page with "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." because, obviously, page 400.html does not exists.

Comment: If garbage text in htaccess didn't generate 500 then it is not being accessed at all.

Comment: Then why ErrorDocument is processed, even if target file is missing?

Comment: `ErrorDocument` can be set somewhere else also.

Answer (score 0):

So, after tried and tried and tried, the string needed to solve my problem was:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

at the top of my htaccess ( here the post who helped me to understand http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/ )